# Software task switching, bearing Out Of Order execution in mind

Tags: cpu

I'm trying to think how Software task switching is implemented with a Tomasulo CPU, what happens to the partially completed instructions in the reservation stations?. When the kernel saves the register state in the process PCB, the register state will be inaccurate for that process if the results haven't yet been written back to the registers (reached the completion stage after ROB). How is this mitigated in a modern CPU? Perhaps it uses the head of the ROB as the program counter (RIP), but that seems wasteful, perhaps a delay is negotiated, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Besides task switching this issue of *'what is the current state of the CPU'* also happens every time there is an interrupt.  Since the CPU must be capable of saving its state in order to process an interrupt, the quandary you pose does have an answer built into the CPU that the OS can emulate for task switching.

Comment: @sawdust after research, my best guess is that the scheduler contains a counter for in flight instructions for a current process, when a timer interrupt occurs, it waits until it gets to 0 before the dispatcher is invoked.